# Android Google Maps Uniquely identify marker onInfoWindowClick

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi I'm using google android maps v2 and adding a bunch of markers to the map however I need to add additional data to the marker objects for recall later in the onInfoWindowClick function.

I currently have a MarkerManager singleton class which maintains a concurrent list of venues however inside the onInfoWindowClick function I need to recall this via some form of key from the MarkerManager.

It appears that markers are static final and can't be extended so I'm a bit stuck on how to do this.

thanks,

Andy

Comment: Maybe putting some code up next time won't get this marked down.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a HashMap:

```
 Map<Marker, YourCustomObject> theMap;
```

Then add the markers as keys:

```
Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.whatever)).position(new LatLng(mLat, mLong)));
theMap.put(m, yourCustomObjectInstance);
```

Finally in your Info Window provider, you can retrieve your object via the marker supplied to the `getInfoWindow` function`:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        YourCustomObject yourCustomObjectInstance = theMap.get(marker);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't end up using the last part (setinfowindowadapter) I just used the marker as a reference from the hashmap and pulled back my object. Are there any reasons why this is would be an issue? Garbage collection?

Comment: No, I thought you needed them in your custom window. I notice now it was for `onInfoWindowClick`. same thing